# C++ (int getopt(argc, (char **)argv, optstring)

Tags: c++

I'm beginner in C++ and using ubuntu 12. I'm having problem in using    the getopt function particularly matching the command line arguments    (int main(int argc, char *argv[]) with optstr in getopt. can anyone    explain what is the format of command line arguments which can be    matched in getopt function.

Comment: Reading the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

The getopt function shuld also have the `#include <unistd.h>`

[Manual page and examples](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)

Comment: Thanks, I have read the manual. Its helpful but i want more clarity like for option character we can user '-' but what can we use for arguments??? and i need to know what should be passed on command line as an argument

g++ monto.cpp -o mc
./mc
how can i pass arguments after ./mc

Comment: // in what format at command line i can pass arguments so this selects option e or others

int init(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int c, errflg = 0;
  while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "de:f:ghm:n:o:pq:r:s:")) != EOF)
    switch(c) 
    {
 cout<<endl<< optarg <<  endl<<endl;
    case 'd':
      DEBUG = 1;
      break;
    case 'e':
      NEL = atoi(optarg);
cout << endl << NEL; 
 break;
    case 'f':
      MFREQ = atoi(optarg);
      break;
    case 'm':
      MTOT = atoi(optarg);
      break;
  
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  init(argc, argv);

return 0;
}